# Отображение данных из бд в xtraGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net, devexpress

Есть таблица в базе данных студентов: `Id`, `имя`, `фамилия`, `год`.

Есть форма с `gridControl`.

В `Grid Designer` добавил три `band`, и три `bandedGrid`. Не могу понять алгоритм, как отобразить в этом гриде данные с БД. C чего начать, что писать? До этого отображал данные с помощью стандартных `WinForms`, но непонятно как работать при подключении *DevExpress*.

Благодарю за любую информацию.

Comment: Что значит есть форма devexpress с гридом, каким гридом, cxGrid?

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос и напишите, что такое "гридом/грид", что такое "винформы", что такое "бендами". Используйте для этого желательно сразу оригинальные английские название.

Comment: спасибо, мне пока еще тяжело формулировать мысль корректно